# How to convert words inputs to a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, set, sorting

I need this for my homework. I'm trying to create a a program where I ask the user for some words. I want those words to be on a list so then I can use `.index` to call some.

I tried to use `.set` or `sorted(set())`. It worked with numbers but not words.   For instance:

```
x = list (raw_input ("insert numbers"))
set = set(x)
result = list(set)
result.sort()
print result
```

From this, I get some good results.  If I feed it numbers, I get the output I expect:

```
insert numbers 817654
[' ', '1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

If I enter words, it sorts the letters:

```
insert numbers now i will a rhyme construct ...
[' ', '.', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'y']
```

The output I *want* is

```
['a', 'construct', 'i', 'now', 'rhyme', 'will']
```

Comment: please post some code of what you have tried

Comment: I have a feeling that you haven't used `.split()`. But like someone else has said, please edit your post to include a sample of the inputs you've tried, and the expected outputs for those inputs

Comment: x = list (raw_input ("insert numbers"))
set = set(x)
result = list(set)
result.sort()
print result

That worked for me... with the numbers, no matter how I entered them... 
My question... can I do that with words?

Comment: as @inspectorG4dget said, use `.split()` method on your `raw_input` call instead of `list` and you will have x be a list of words from the input

Comment: `words = sorted(set(raw_input("Enter words: ").split()))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All we need to do from your original attempt is to turn the input into a word list *before* we do any more processing.  I see that inspectorG4dget already did the one-line solution to this -- make sure to vote up his comment.  If you replace "words =" with "print", there's your whole program.  Closer to your terms is this code:

```
x = raw_input ("insert numbers")
word_list = x.split(' ')
set = set(word_list)
result = list(set)
result.sort()
print result
```

@inspectorG4dget, if you care to post your solution as an explained response, I'll be happy to delete this posting in your favor: your comment came in while I was editing the question.

Comment: @-replies don't work outside of comments or chat. In the future, don't worry about "stealing" from comments; best to just keep your answer straightforward for readers who don't care at all about the conversational bits (though in this case, it's a dupe and not really worth answering)